# discord.py: Inexplicable Missing Access error

Tags: python, discord.py

I try to do a bot, who makes temporary Voice Channels. There's a command which "locks" the channel. Means nobody can join anymore.

Code who locks the channel:

```py
# line 381 
permstemplock = {
  ctx.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(connect=False),
  ctx.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True, manage_roles=True,
                                            manage_channels=True, manage_permissions=True),
  ctx.author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(manage_channels=True, connect=True,view_channel=True),
}

await tempc.edit(overwrites=permstemplock)
```

And the opposite of the lock command, unlock:

```
permstempunlock = {
  ctx.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True, manage_roles=True, manage_channels=True,
                                                                              manage_permissions=True),
  ctx.author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(manage_channels=True, connect=True,view_channel=True),

}

await tempc.edit(overwrites=permstempunlock)
```

Server permissions of the bot:

```
- Create Invite
- Manage Channels
- View Channels
- Send messages
- Manage messages
- Embed links
- Attached Files
- View message history
- Use external emojis
- Add reactions
- Move members
- Use Voice Activity
```

Error:

```
Ignoring exception in command voice:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:/DiscordBot/PyCharm/AmongUsDeutsch/Tempchannels/tempchannels.py", line 381, in voice
    await tempc.edit(overwrites=permstempunlock)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 694, in edit
    await self._edit(options, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 309, in _edit
    data = await self._state.http.edit_channel(self.id, reason=reason, **options)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 241, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

The Bot (`ctx.guild.me`) needs the permission `connect`. Doing `connect = True` solved the problem:

```
permstemplock = {
  ctx.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(connect=False),
  ctx.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True, manage_roles=True,
                                            manage_channels=True, manage_permissions=True, connect=True),
  ctx.author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(manage_channels=True, connect=True,view_channel=True),
}

await tempc.edit(overwrites=permstemplock)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=forbidden#discord.Forbidden): The error is thrown when [status code 403](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/opcodes-and-status-codes) occurs. In other words, you're bot doesn't have access to the channel. This is probably because the channel is syncing permissions with the category which is disabling the bot its needed permissions.

You can fix this by setting up your role perm or category perm hierarchy so the bot will have access to all channels that are created.

Another possible cause is that you're locking the permissions for **@everyone** first which is locking the bots permissions. If this is the case, just add the line **ctx.guild.me** before the **ctx.guild.default_role** line.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will test it as soon as I'm at home. But I have a question. You said that a possible cause could be that `ctx.guild.default_role` is before `ctx.guild.me` and it's locking the bot permissions. Thats true for this command. But if the bot have to change the permissions again we have the same problem as before, haven't we?