# Discord.py raises weird Error that doesn't describe Exception

Tags: python, discord.py

I already worked with discord.py a bit but this never happend.
The pretty much same thing even worked minuted earlier in a a bit different way so yeah just look:

```
    async def on_ready(self):
        global BotCommandsChannel
        BotCommandsChannel = await self.fetch_channel(838442070326247496)
        await BotCommandsChannel.send("Der Bot hat restarted und ist jetzt wieder on!")

    async def on_message(self, message):
        a = 0


Main().run("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
```

The exception:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\x\PycharmProjects\x\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\x\PycharmProjects\x\main.py", line 10, in on_ready
    BotCommandsChannel = await self.fetch_channel(838442070326247496)
  File "C:\Users\x\PycharmProjects\x\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 1459, in fetch_channel
    data = await self.http.get_channel(channel_id)
  File "C:\Users\x\PycharmProjects\x\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 248, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access
```

So yeah the Bot has permissions to get channels and also (get didn't work i had to use fetch) the channel exists

If i remove the fetch and make it a get then it returns zero

Sry for my bad English I'm German

Comment: Can the bot see the channel? Have a look at [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65028498/discord-py-missing-access-error-why-and-how-can-i-fix-it-solution-found). Also why do you use `self.fetch`? That does not exist. It is either `self.bot` or `self.client` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your bot has enough permissions that it needs. Because the error seems to be related with permissions. Take Admin permission if it is in development.